# Partition elimination in Greenplum

Tags: sql, postgresql, partition, greenplum

I have a scenario like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PACKAGE WHERE PACKAGE_TYPE IN ('BOX','CARD')
```

The table is partitioned by `PACKAGE_TYPE` field. Assume that there are twenty possible values for `PACKAGE_TYPE` field. So there are twenty partitions including `BOX`, `CARD` and `DEFAULT` partitions. When the above query is run, partition elimination happens correctly and only the `BOX` and `CARD`partitions get scanned. The result is quick.

However, when the same query is written like this:

`SELECT * FROM PACKAGE WHERE PACKAGE_TYPE IN (SELECT PACKAGE_TYPE FROM PACKAGE_LIST_TABLE)`, where the column `PACKAGE_TYPE` in `PACKAGE_LIST_TABLE` contains two values `BOX` and `CARD`.

When the above query is run, all the 20 partitions are being scanned. It degrades the performance.

It seems that the compiler is failing to identify the second query correctly and as a result all the partitions are getting accessed.

Any workarounds to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Partition elimination would normally happen during the compiling phase of the query execution.  The list of needed partitions is unknown at this time.

Comment: Thanks. Any workarounds to get this work? It is not possible to "hard code" the values in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Postgres manual page on Partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html) includes this caveat

> Constraint exclusion only works when the query's WHERE clause contains constants (or externally supplied parameters). For example, a comparison against a non-immutable function such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP cannot be optimized, since the planner cannot know which partition the function value might fall into at run time.

In order to eliminate a seek on a partition, Postgres must know *when creating a query plan* that no rows from that partition are relevant. In your query, this occurs only after the sub-query has completed, so the query would have to be split into two, with the second part planned only after the first completes.

If the partitions include an index on the partitioned column (`PACKAGE_TYPE`) as well as a constraint, the planner *may* elect to use an index scan on each partition, leading to the incorrect partitions being reasonably efficiently eliminated at runtime anyway. (That is, there would be 20 index scans, but each would require very little resource.)

An alternative would be to split the query yourself, and build the SQL dynamically. Since the `SELECT PACKAGE_TYPE FROM PACKAGE_LIST_TABLE` can only ever return up to 20 distinct values, you could select those into an array/set in your application or a user-defined function. Then you can pass these in as literals in the `IN ( ... )` clause as in your first example (or equivalently `= ANY(array_expression)`), and achieve the partition elimination.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got this. I have only one question. I tried building the SQL dynamically. But it seems like array doesn't get recognized by the compiler and I get this error:
ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown || character varying[]

Comment: My execute statement looks like this: ARRVAR character varying[];
ARRVAR := ARRAY(SELECT PACKAGE_ID FROM PACKAGE_LIST_TABLE);   
execute 'UPDATE PACKAGE_TYPE SET PACKAGE_DT = CURRENT_DATE WHERE PACKAGE_ID = any('||ARRVAR||')';  
What am I missing? How do I get array to work in dynamic query?

Comment: That error isn't to do with the dynamic query, it's because you're trying to concatenate the array into a string, and Postgres doesn't know what you mean by that. I don't have an environment at hand to check, but I think you can get away without a dynamic SQL string at all within a function, by just writing `UPDATE PACKAGE_TYPE SET PACKAGE_DT = CURRENT_DATE WHERE PACKAGE_ID = any(ARRVAR);`

Comment: Thanks. I tried giving a direct UPDATE statement inside the function. But the query was taking times similar to a query that doesn't have WHERE clause on partition column. Since the query was inside a function, I wasn't able to verify if it hit all partitions or not as postgres did not show anything about partition scans when I ran explain analyze. However I understood that partition elimination did not happen seeing the overall run time. So option is either to give it as a dynamic query or append all the package ids, store it in one character variable and then put it in WHERE clause.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a way from your hint - " trying to concatenate the array into a string". I used this - CHARVAR := ''''||array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT PACKAGE_ID FROM PACKAGE_LIST_TABLE), ''',''')||''''; .

Comment: IMSoP, the partition elimination problem resurfaced with an insert statement even after substituting the where clause with a character variable and running it as dynamic query. The partition elimination did not happen when insert was run and query seems to take long times. UPDATE still works fine with the partition elimination. Are there any differences by the way INSERT and UPDATE statements get executed in a dynamic query?